# Assign strings to IDs in Python

Tags: python, string

I am reading a text file with python, formatted where the values in each column may be numeric or strings.

When those values are strings, I need to assign a unique ID of that string (unique across all the strings under the same column; the same ID must be assigned if the same string appears elsewhere under the same column).

What would be an efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 12):

Use a defaultdict with a default value factory that generates new ids:

```
ids = collections.defaultdict(itertools.count().next)
ids['a']  # 0
ids['b']  # 1
ids['a']  # 0
```

When you look up a key in a defaultdict, if it's not already present, the defaultdict calls a user-provided default value factory to get the value and stores it before returning it.

`collections.count()` creates an iterator that counts up from 0, so `collections.count().next` is a bound method that produces a new integer whenever you call it.

Combined, these tools produce a dict that returns a new integer whenever you look up something you've never looked up before.

Comment: This is not what he asked?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: How so?

Comment: This should do exactly what he needs.  If he's iterating through rows of data, each unique value gets a unique integer by simple insertion.  Duplicate checking is built in.

Comment: He asked to only assign values to _strings_ not each column: _"**When those values are strings**, I need to assign a unique ID of that string (unique across all the strings under the same column; the same ID must be assigned if the same string appears elsewhere under the same column)."_ He can get a running counter by just enumerating over the file.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: So he looks up the string in the defaultdict and gets its ID. What's the problem? EDIT: Are you looking at an old version of the answer? The first version (gone now) just had the counter, without the defaultdict, since I didn't see the requirement of assigning the same ID to a string if it shows up twice.

Comment: Whoa, that's a neat use of `itertools.count` and `defaultdict`. Cool!!

Comment: You still haven't solved the problem. If the same string appears in two columns, it needs a different id.  You have a solution (very neat, by the way), but it is not solving his problem.

Comment: @user2357112 I dont understand this solution. Could you please explain? When I tried to execute this, for any value of `ids` I get `0`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Does it? I'm not sure. If so, you can make defaultdicts for each column.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Really? Odd. When you look up a key in a defaultdict, if it's not already present, the defaultdict calls a user-provided default value factory to get the value and stores it before returning it. `collections.count()` creates an iterator that counts up from 0, so `collections.count().next` is a bound method that produces a new integer whenever you call it. Combined, these tools produce a dict that returns a new integer whenever you look up something you've never looked up before.

Comment: @user2357112 Thats awesome. Please add this explanation to your answer. I ll upvote :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: Explanation added to the answer.

Comment: @AndyHayden: Yeah, for Python 3, it's `__next__` instead of `next`.

Answer (score 2):

defaultdict answer updated for python 3, where `.next` is now `.__next__`, and for pylint compliance, where using "magic" `__*__` methods is discouraged:

```
ids = collections.defaultdict(functoools.partial(next, itertools.count()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a set, and then add strings to the set. This will ensure that strings are not duplicated; then you can use enumerate to get a unique id of each string.  Use this ID when you are writing the file out again.

Here I am assuming the second column is the one you want to scan for text or integers.

```
seen = set()
with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   for row in reader:
      try:
         int(row[1])
      except ValueError:
         seen.add(row[1]) # adds string to set

# print the unique ids for each string

for id,text in enumerate(seen):
    print("{}: {}".format(id, text))
```

Now you can take the same logic, and replicate it across each column of your file. If you know the column length in advanced, you can have a list of sets. Suppose the file has three columns:

```
unique_strings = [set(), set(), set()]

with open('file.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
       for column,value in enumerate(row):
           try:
               int(value)
           except ValueError:
               # It is not an integer, so it must be
               # a string
               unique_strings[column].add(value)
```