# Replacing python list elements with key

Tags: python, list, key

I have a list of non-unique strings:

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d", "b"]
```

I would like to replace each element with an integer key which uniquely identifies each string:

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1]
```

The number does not matter, as long as it is a unique identifier.

So far all I can think to do is copy the list to a set, and use the index of the set to reference the list.  I'm sure there's a better way though.

Comment: Are all of the "strings" single characters as you have here?  If so, you could consider using the [ord](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) function.  [Sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) do not support indexing.

Comment: Not necessarily, no.

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, as that shadows the built-in `list` type. It won't hurt anything here, but it can lead to mysterious bugs if your script later tries to use the `list` type to construct a list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will guarantee uniqueness and that the id's are contiguous starting from `0`:

```
id_s = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(set(list))}
li = [id_s[c] for c in list]
```

On a different note, you should not use `'list'` as variable name because it will shadow the built-in type `list`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a single pass solution with [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
seen = defaultdict()
seen.default_factory = lambda: len(seen)  # you could instead bind to seen.__len__

In [11]: [seen[c] for c in list]
Out[11]: [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1]
```

*It's kind of a trick but worth mentioning!*

---

An alternative, [suggested by @user2357112 in a related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605500/assign-strings-to-ids-in-python/18605520#18605520), is to increment with [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count). This allows you to do this just in the constructor:

```
from itertools import count
seen = defaultdict(count().__next__)  # .next in python 2
```

*This may be preferable as the default_factory method won't look up `seen` in global scope.*

Comment: Very clever, I like it! I had never thought about using that kind of reflexive powers in the `default_factory`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I *guess* that's what the attributes is there for (rather than being private), still I had hoped they'd be a single constructor way to do it (and reference self)... it feels a little dirty/old school. :/

Comment: [`itertools.count().next` also works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605500/assign-strings-to-ids-in-python/18605520#18605520) for the `default_factory`, or you could use `seen = defaultdict(lambda: len(seen))`, since `seen` doesn't need to exist yet to create the lambda. I prefer `itertools.count().next` to `lambda: len(seen)`, since it doesn't require inspecting the dict's state in the middle of a mutative operation, but either version feels like there's too much magic going on in the `default_factory`.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't think it's too much magic, that's what it is it there for! It's annoying that the itertools.count api is different for python 3 (you need to use `__next__`) but I agree the itertools.count is much nicer that len (though both are O(1)).

Comment: @user2357112 I missed the lambda part... the worse part is it looks up the `seen` variable in scope (which could dirtily be avoided by binding to `seen.__len__` (if only [len were a proper oo method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237128/is-there-a-reason-python-strings-dont-have-a-string-length-method#comment9848314_237150)). This really needs to be created in a function to avoid that. Your solution is better!

Comment: to avoid the dichotomy between Python 2 and 3, consider `defaultdict(lambda: next(count))` where `count = itertools.count()`.

Comment: @codesparkle and if you do that consider defining it in a function (so that the count variable doesn't leak, like the seen variable above).

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> lst = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d", "b"]
>>> nums = [ord(x) for x in lst]
>>> print(nums)
[97, 98, 99, 97, 97, 100, 98]
```

Comment: This works only if each item in the list is a single character, which the OP has said (in a comment) my not be so.

Comment: This could also do with a little bit of explanation IMO.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not picky, then use the hash function: it returns an integer. For strings that are the same, it returns the same hash:

```
li = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d", "b"]
li = map(hash, li)                # Turn list of strings into list of ints
li = [hash(item) for item in li]  # Same as above
```

Comment: This does work, assuming dynamic results are acceptable. Good one.

Comment: This does not work. Hashes are not guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d", "b", "abc", "def", "abc"]
from itertools import count
from operator import itemgetter

mapped = itemgetter(*l)(dict(zip(l, count())))
```

You could also use a simple generator function:

```
from itertools import count

def uniq_ident(l):
    cn,d  = count(), {}
    for ele in l:
        if ele not in d:
            c = next(cn)
            d[ele] = c
            yield c
        else:
            yield d[ele]


In [35]: l = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d", "b"]

In [36]: list(uniq_ident(l))
Out[36]: [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1]
```

Comment: try with `l = ["\t\t", "c"]`